# Foolproof multiple validators on the same fields

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, foolproof-validation

I currently use foolproof for that validation:

```
[RequiredIfNot("type", 3, ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least one value")]
public int[] audites { get; set; }
```

but customer wants to add validation as that:

```
[RequiredIfNot("type", 3, ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least one value")]
[RequiredIfNot("nature", 1, ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least one value")]
[RequiredIfNot("nature", 3, ErrorMessage = "Please enter at least one value")]
public int[] audites { get; set; }
```

But it compilator disagree with that, so how can In combine both?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does _" it compilator disagree with that"_ mean? Does it not compile? Does it not work at runtime?

Comment: it doesn't want to compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Foolproof.RequiredIfNotAttribute` derives from `Foolproof.ModelAwareValidationAttribute` (which in turn derives from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.ValidationAttribute`). `ModelAwareValidationAttribute` is marked with `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]`. [Refer source code](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Foolproof/Base%20Classes/ModelAwareValidationAttribute.cs). By default the the `AllowMultiple` parameter of `AttributeUsage` is `false` which means that you can only apply the attribute once to a property. You have tried to apply it 3 times, hence the error.

Having it `true` and allowing it to be applied multiple times would possibly cause problems in setting the `$.validator.methods` and `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters` functions used by unobtrusive validation.

You will need to use some other validation attributes or create your own `ValidationAtribute` that implements `IClientValidatable`, or rely on server side validation.