# Validating more than one field with Fool Proof

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, model, data-annotations, foolproof-validation

Hello I'm using MVC [**Fool Proof Validation.**](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) to validate my model, and i need to use `RequiredIfNotEmpty` with two fields but i'm getting issues with it

**Model**

```
public class Conexionado{

    [DisplayName("Conexión")]
    [RequiredIfNotEmpty("Conex_BT2_Pos", ErrorMessage = "Error!")]
    [RequiredIfNotEmpty("Conex_BT2_N", ErrorMessage = "Conex_BT2 Cant be empty if Conex_BT2_N isnt!")]
    public string Conex_BT2 { get; set; }

    public string Conex_BT2_N { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Ángulo BT")]
    [Range(0, 11, ErrorMessage = "Incorrect number")]
    public int? Conex_BT2_Pos { get; set; }

}
```

I have tried some like

```
[RequiredIfNotEmpty("Conex_BT2_Pos , Conex_BT2_N", ErrorMessage = "Error!")]

[RequiredIfNotEmpty("Conex_BT2_Pos || Conex_BT2_N", ErrorMessage = "Error!")]
```

But in this case, i can compile, but when i try to use `Conex_BT2` i get

> 'System.NullReferenceException' en FoolproofValidation.dll

Someone know how i must deal with it?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to create you own custom validation attribute. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28504122/foolproof-multiple-validators-on-the-same-fields/28512316#28512316) explains why you cannot apply the same `ValidationAttribute` more than once. For a good article to get you started, refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2). Have a go, and if your still having problems, post what you have tried

Answer (score -1):

This question has been answered here:

> [Foolproof multiple validators on the same fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28512316/8933039) by [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke)

The `Foolproof.RequiredIfNotAttribute` derives from `Foolproof.ModelAwareValidationAttribute` (which in turn derives from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.ValidationAttribute`). `ModelAwareValidationAttribute` is marked with `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]`. [Refer source code](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Foolproof/Base%20Classes/ModelAwareValidationAttribute.cs). By default the the `AllowMultiple` parameter of `AttributeUsage` is `false` which means that you can only apply the attribute once to a property. You have tried to apply it 3 times, hence the error.

Having it `true` and allowing it to be applied multiple times would possibly cause problems in setting the `$.validator.methods` and `$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters` functions used by unobtrusive validation.

You will need to use some other validation attributes or create your own `ValidationAtribute` that implements `IClientValidatable`, or rely on server side validation.

> You can implement custom validations in the model properties. See this tutorial: [Creating Custom Validation Attribute in MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301022/Creating-Custom-Validation-Attribute-in-MVC) to create a custom validation attribute to do the work you need, where you should write your own jquery validation script for client side validation in MVC framework mode if using IClientValidatable , which is also explained in it.

Good luck, greetings!

Comment: When I was reviewing your answer, I didn't realise that you were linking to another SO answer. That is an indication that the question is a duplicate, so you really should flag the question as a duplicate, rather than try to replicate the answer. I didn't give you the downvote, btw, but linking to other SO answers will leave you open to such actions from other users.

Comment: @DeanOC I have not marked it as a duplicate, because with my reputation I can not vote to mark it like this, now I have edited my response and I have added additional information